# Read data from a particular port and specified IP using java

Tags: java, sockets, port, serversocket

I would like to read the messages from a particular port.For example the IP is 1.2.3.4 and the port is 1000. Already the IP is used for receiving some messages. What I would like to    do is to listen to that particular IP and receive all the messages using a java program. Will
SocketServer do the purpose??

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1000);
Socket socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4",1000);
socket = ss.accept();
```

Is it possible to read every contents that are being received by the particular IP and port?

Comment: @HussainAl-Mutawa the latter part!! A java program somewhere else and listen to all messages that are sent to 1.2.3.4 ..

Comment: Bare in mind, that in some systems You cannot use easily ports below 1024. Just to be on the safe side, pick some greater port number.

Comment: @Lauri No worries for that because it is a dedicated port to receive data.

Comment: What OS are You using for the server? Under which user privileges You run your server program?

Comment: Your code is a mixture of server and client. In a server, you get each Socket via accept(), and you don't have line 2. In a client, you only have line 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To listen to a specific address you have to create a ServerSocket like this

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(); // Unbound socket
ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 1000)); // Bind the socket to a specific interface
Socket client = ss.accept();
```

This way the server socket is bound to a specific network interface and will only receive incoming connections from it.

Comment: ohh.. thanks for that quick reply.. but the program returned with this error :     ' java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)'

Comment: @user1640534 That's either the port is used or because this address is not bound to any of your network interfaces.